# Network printer problem

Tags: networking

This may sound like a silly question from a newbie,but is their a way to add a network printer to my Zubuntu 14.04 that I just downloaded? I can't seem to find where to add it yet.

Comment: Zubuntu? What is it?

Comment: @Lucio: it's one way you *pronounce* Xubuntu due to English having such clear 1:1 mappings between written and spoken language (NOT!) ;)

Comment: It's pronunced XZHKoonmntoock btw ^^.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the System Settings icon (gear & wrench). In there, there's a Printers icon. Click on it. ("One ping only...") That should bring up a window for adding printers. Click on Add, and it should (eventually) bring up a list of Printers that it can find, locally and on the network. If you then select one, you should be on your way.